# Javascript- displaying words with charAt one letter+one letter and so on

Tags: javascript, charat

So im trying to display words typed in my textbox as following example: (thomas) would display as= "t, th, tho, thom, thoma, thomas". What do i input in charAt to make that happen? or do i need to add something else? Thanks in advance!

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

 <script>

    function printit()
    {
     var temptext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;   
     var tempa = temptext.charAt();
     document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML=tempa;

    }

 </script>


 </head>


 <body>
   <h1> </h1> 

<form name="f1">
 <input type="text" id="mytext" value="" />
 <input type="button"  value="print" onclick="printit()"/>

 </form>
 <div id="translated"  style="background-color:gray"></div> 

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) within a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) would be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ES6 solution using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string/slice) methods.

```html
<script>
  function printit() {
    var temptext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
    document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML = Array.from({
      length: temptext.length
    }, (v, i) => temptext.slice(0, i + 1)).join();

  }
</script>


<form name="f1">
  <input type="text" id="mytext" value="" />
  <input type="button" value="print" onclick="printit()" />

</form>
<div id="translated" style="background-color:gray"></div>
```

---

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string/split) methods.

```html
<script>
  function printit() {
    var temptext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
    document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML = temptext.split('').map(function(v, i) {
      return temptext.slice(0, i + 1)
    }).join();

  }
</script>


<form name="f1">
  <input type="text" id="mytext" value="" />
  <input type="button" value="print" onclick="printit()" />

</form>
<div id="translated" style="background-color:gray"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution :

```js
function writemore(){
    var a = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
    var out = [];
    for(var i=1;i<a.length+1;i++){
       out.push(a.substring(0,i));
    }
    document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML = out.join(',');
};
```

```html
<form name="f1">
  <input type="text" id="mytext" value="" />
  <input type="button" value="print" onclick="writemore();" />

</form>
<div id="translated" style="background-color:gray"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) and [`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) for generating the expected result.

```js
function printit(){
  var text = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
  document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML = text.split('').map(function(v, i){ return text.slice(0, i + 1)}).join(', ');
}
```

```html
<h1> </h1> 

<form name="f1">
  <input type="text" id="mytext" value="" />
  <input type="button" value="print" onclick="printit()" />

</form>
<div id="translated" style="background-color:gray"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to display "t, th, tho, thom, thoma, thomas" you should to store your position of charAt(position+1) and make for condition.., so :

t : 0==> display  = display  + ", "+ charAt(position+1)
th : 1==> display  = display  + ", "+ charAt(position+1)
tho: 2 ==> display  = display  + ", "+  charAt(position+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way, if you're set on using charAt, would be this:

```
var outputString = "", inputString = "Thomas", i = -1, inputLength = inputString.length

while(++i < inputLength){
  outputString += inputString.charAt(i)
  console.log(outputString)
}
```

If it literally needs to print "t, th, tho, thom, thoma, thomas" and not a sequence of logs, this version would accomplish that

```
var outputString = "", outputArray = [], inputString = "Thomas", i = -1, inputLength = inputString.length

while(++i < inputLength){
  outputString += inputString.charAt(i)
  outputArray.push(outputString)
}


console.log(outputArray.join(", "))
```